# Android multiple image with volley passing parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to upload multiple images with this code, and it works. The problem I am having is that I am passing them through one place `params.put(KEY_IMAGE, encodedString)`. Rather than that, I want to pass them through multiple keys, so it will be easier to locate them after in PHP.

**Choosing an image:**

```
ChooseBn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent in = galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent();
        in.setType("image/*");
        in.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(in, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }
});
```

**Uploading an image:**

```
final MyCommand myCommand = new MyCommand(getApplicationContext());

UploadBn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (String imagePath : imageList) {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = PhotoLoader.init().from(imagePath).requestSize(500, 500).getBitmap();
                final String encodedString = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);

                String url = "http://192.168.100.3/upload.php";
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {

                    String name = NAME.getText().toString().trim();
                    String lat = LAT.getText().toString().trim();
                    String lng = LNG.getText().toString().trim();

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                        params.put(KEY_IMAGE, encodedString);
                        params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
                        params.put(KEY_LAT, lat);
                        params.put(KEY_LNG, lng);

                        return params;
                    }
                };

                myCommand.add(stringRequest);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while loading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have multiple images, then you should encode them separately.

Comment: That's quite obvious, how do I separate every image? imageList is an ArrayList<>();

Comment: I see that you have the list, so what isn't working exactly? Does your PHP accept whatever the value of the `KEY_IMAGE` variable is correctly ?

Comment: Yes the php file accepts key_image value,it runs. The problem is that I need every image to be a different variable, simple because I can't figure how to address them to multiple columns of the DB(image1,image2,image3.. with the same unique id)

Comment: One thing that I did try is using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and that works also, but I need that up to 5 images not 2.

Comment: That sounds like a PHP / MySQL problem rather than Android. If you want to send all the images at once, then do that instead of looping over a list

Comment: Cough-cough how do I do that? I really don't care if I solve it within the app or php, I already asked for the php solution and of course got 0 help.

Comment: As the answer below illustrates, you could place all encoded images into an array of strings, then send that in just one request.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches come to my mind.

In both of them you need a custom `Image` class:

```
public class Image {
    public String imageString;
    public String name;
    public double lat, lng;
}
```

**Quick solution using `toString()`:**

Use [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) and pass it as parameter.

So instead of invoking API for individual `imagePath` in `imageList`, you will add individual `Image` object to the request as a parameter as follows:

```
for (String imagePath : imageList) { 
    Image image = new Image();
    // Set image's properties here
    params.add(image.name, image.toString());
}
```

You either parse whatever you write in `Image.toString()` or better yet you can actually return the object in JSON form to simplify reparsing on server:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(this);
}
```

**Better solution:**

The better solution uses `JsonArrayRequest` to pass all `Image` objects together using already built `Image` class and Gson parsing.

```
JSONArray imageArray = null;
try {
    imageArray = new JSONArray(gson.toJson(imageList)); // Note that imageList is List<Image> and not List<String>
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, imageArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
});
```

> Note that in both these solutions you have to get image string by parsing JSON that you'll receive on the server. In return for this effort, you get a nice structure to your requests.

Comment: Mate, sorry if dumb/offensive, but I understand nothing of the both suggested. I don't see how to implement/try it as separate parameters.

Comment: Simply put, send your image and related attributes as JSON string and parse them back on server.

Comment: You overestimate my understanding of this by a mile.Let me make it super simple, taking the code from suggestion 1. How do I access the images from PHP in the form" $_POST['image'];"

Comment: Better to use a StringRequest since the result of the Volley call isn't guaranteed to be an array